# How to get live mempool transactions whitout full blokchain

Tags: blockchain, python, bitcoin, memory

I just want to analyse all mempool txs in realtime.
I cant use an api because after several requests my ip gets blocked for some minutes, so I dont get the txs in this time. 
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is an official answer from `geth`.

> You need to fork the code and figure out how to remove all non-txpool related functionality.
> This is not something that we are going to support in go-ethereum though.

https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/23537#issuecomment-913654323

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible to stream pending transactions without relying on a (full) node to facilitate those requests for you. Maybe once [light clients](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/#light-node) become more mature you can do this without.

You mention API's are not an option, but most infra service providers (e.g. [Infura](https://docs.infura.io/infura/tutorials/ethereum/subscribe-to-pending-transactions), [Alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-track-mined-and-pending-ethereum-transactions), [Quicknode](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/web3-sdks/how-to-stream-pending-transactions-with-ethersjs) or [Blocknative](https://docs.blocknative.com/mempool-explorer)) have drastically improved over the years. Most provide methods to fetch pending transactions either over RPC or their APIs.

E.g. you can subscribe to a stream of 'pending' transactions which emit events as soon as they hit the mempool.

A simple example using [Ethers](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider--events)

```
import { providers } from "ethers"

const provider = getDefaultProvider()
provider.on('pending', (tx) => console.log('Tx', tx))
```

Alternatively, depending on your execution client you can fetch the content of the current txpool. This is not a standard call and implementation varies between clients.

- [Geth](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-txpool) `txpool_content`
- [Nethermind](https://docs.nethermind.io/nethermind/ethereum-client/json-rpc/txpool) `txpool_content`
- [Erigon](https://github.com/ledgerwatch/erigon/blob/devel/cmd/rpcdaemon/README.md#rpc-implementation-status) `txpool_content`
- [Besu](https://besu.hyperledger.org/en/stable/public-networks/reference/api/#txpool-methods) `txpool_besuPendingTransactions` - this is the main outlier

E.g. using Ethers again

```
import { providers } from "ethers"

const provider = getDefaultProvider()
const poolContent = await provider.send('txpool_content', [])
```

or Curl

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"txpool_content","params":[],"id":1}' https://bordel.xyz/
```